# Is it acceptable to repeatedly pray for the same thing?

Tags: prayer

Its very common among christians today to pray for the same thing over and over again...

Now does it mean God does not hear our payers that we should pray for the same things repeatedly.. Psalm 94:9 reads "He who implanted the ear, shall He not hear? He who fashioned the eyes, shall He see?. So then I would want to know whether its right for a christian believer to pray repeatedly..

Does it mean we lack faith?

Comment: Parable of the Insistent Widow: Luke 18:1-8

Answer (score 2):

It is more than acceptable for Christians to pray without ceasing and also for the same intentions.

The Scriptures tell us to "pray without ceasing" 1Thessalonians.

Luke 18:1-8New International Version (NIV)

The Parable of the Persistent Widow (Luke 18:1-8) is another fine example.

18 Then Jesus told his disciples a parable to show them that they should always pray and not give up. 2 He said: “In a certain town there was a judge who neither feared God nor cared what people thought. 3 And there was a widow in that town who kept coming to him with the plea, ‘Grant me justice against my adversary.’

4 “For some time he refused. But finally he said to himself, ‘Even though I don’t fear God or care what people think, 5 yet because this widow keeps bothering me, I will see that she gets justice, so that she won’t eventually come and attack me!’”

6 And the Lord said, “Listen to what the unjust judge says. 7 And will not God bring about justice for his chosen ones, who cry out to him day and night? Will he keep putting them off? 8 I tell you, he will see that they get justice, and quickly. However, when the Son of Man comes, will he find faith on the earth?”

Sometimes we have to pray often in order to get a response from the Almighty and at times the answer will be no! The story of how Abraham pleaded to save Sodom (Genesis 18:16-33) could be used as an example here. This story can also show us that even though Abraham pleaded for the city of Sodom, the city was eventually destroyed.

At times God may not grant a response to our prayers immediately, for whatever reasons He Himself is privy to, whether to build up our faith or for some other reason. In the [List of Approved Lourdes Miracles](http://www.miraclehunter.com/marian_apparitions/approved_apparitions/lourdes/miracles4.html), some of the miraculous healing occurred only after a repeated visit(s) to the Grotto. I offer this last example only as an example to show that we, at times, must be quite persistent in prayer in order to find favor with God.

When we say grace before meals is it not only befitting, also encouraged to ask God's blessing on the poor and the hungry!